# Gibt es einen kürzeren Ausdruck für "abgerundete Ecke"?

Tags: single-word-request, idiom

Gibt es ein Wort oder einen kürzeren Ausdruck für "abgerundete Ecke"?

Beispielsatz:

> Ich bevorzuge diesen Bildschirm (dieses Bücherregal), denn er (es) hat abgerundete Ecken (Kanten).

Comment: "gerundete Ecke" ist zwei Zeichen kürzer. ;)

Comment: @splattne: Hier fehlen jetzt eindeutig die adäquaten Smilies, um dir zu antworten.

Comment: LOL (lautes Online-Lachen)!

Comment: @splattne Das ist nicht der Smilie, an den ich dachte :)

Comment: Du wolltest mir das Wort *Bruder* in taiwanesicher Gebärdensprache zeigen? http://www.futilitycloset.com/2011/05/29/warm-words-2/

Comment: sehr umgangssprachlich: "rundgelutscht"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mir ist kein kürzerer allgemeingültiger Ausdruck bekannt.

@MusiKk's Vorschlag funktioniert für Möbel (da aber auch nur in Bezug auf ihre Gesamtform, nicht für  abgeschliffene Ecken), ist sonst meines Wissens aber nirgendwo in Gebrauch.

Answer (score 6):

Rundung. Colani verpasste Alltagsgegenständen Rundungen, wo vormals Ecken waren.

Allerdings ist Rundung weiter gefasst und kann sich auch nur auf eine oder wenige Kanten beziehen.

[image]

Das letzte Bild zeigt die Ecke des Bildes darüber, aber an 2 Ebenen aufgeschnitten. In der Praxis sind natürlich nicht alle Ecken ideal kugelrund gerundet, sondern können gestaucht/gestreckt sein in eine oder mehrere Richtungen und in der Mitte auch abgeflacht sein. Man kann auch 2 D-förmige Profile aufeinanderstoßen lassen und mit der Gehrungssäge so schneiden, dass sich auf der Schnittkante keine Rundung ergibt, sondern eine gekrümmte Kante im Raum.

Comment: Eine "Rundung" kann sich aber auch auf eine ansonsten gerade Kante beziehen (die stattdessen gerundet, also in Bögen geschwungen verläuft), nicht notwendigerweise auf eine Ecke.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Du meinst die Rundung geht nur über 2 der 3 Dimensionen? Das kann sein, ja. Um Zweifeln vorzubeugen könnte man "Kugelrundung" sagen - gebräuchlich ist das aber nicht. Vielleicht gibt es in Fachjargons (Gelenkbau der Ingenieure) Begriffe die ich nicht kenne. Du kennst aber auch nichts besseres?

Comment: Nein, ich meine, bei einer "Rundung" ist nicht klar, ob sie sich überhaupt an einer Ecke befindet. Stell dir ein Regalbrett vor - wenn es "abgerundete Ecken" hat, denke ich zuerst daran, dass das Brett zwar seine (von oben gesehen) grundlegende Rechteckform beibehält, dass aber die Ecken eben nicht 90°-eckig sind, sondern abgerundet. Hat das Brett einfach eine "Rundung", so könnte es sich auch um ein Halbkreis-, Mondsichel-, Mandel-förmiges oder sonstwie gerundetes Brett handeln.

Comment: Wären das nicht auch 2 von 3 Dimensionen? Also wir hätten ein quaderförmiges Regalbrett in der Ausgangssituation. Die längste Seite 1m lang A, die Breite. Die Tiefe B 30cm. Die Brettdicke C 2cm. Jetzt könnte man das Brett flach auf die Werkbank legen und die Ecken vorne links und rechts mit einer Stichsäge senkrecht viertelkreisförmig absägen. Die linke und rechte, senkrechte Kante wäre weg.. Die Kante horizontal oben und in die Tiefe links/rechts wären nach wie vor eckig. Über die 2cm Brettdicke könnte und würde man das nicht machen. 30cm und mehr hat wohl kaum eine Stichsäge.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Nähme man vorne und an der Seite halbkreisförmig Material mit dem Bandschleifer fort würde an der Ecke automatisch von 2 Seiten Material weggenomen. Man hätte eine ¼-Kugelform. Bei anderen Formen könnte am Treffpunkt wieder eine Kante entstehen. Oder man rundet nur eine Seite ab, sagen wir vorne. Dan sieht das Brett von der Seite wie ein sehr, sehr breites D aus. Das wären alles Rundungen, ja, aber nicht unbedingt solche der Ecke. Rundung ist also zu allgemein.

Comment: [Auf diesem Bild](http://i.imgur.com/yTp87xl.png) siehst du zwei Regalbretter von oben. Beide haben Rundungen. Aber nur das obere hat abgerundete Ecken.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26873/discussion-between-user-unknown-and-o-r-mapper).

Answer (score 3):

Der "Beweis durch Google" zeigt, dass die Begriffe "Rundecke" und "Rundkante" halbwegs gebräuchlich sind, vor allem in der Möbelbranche. "Rundkante" klingt nach meinem Dafürhalten eher technisch, aber "Rundecke" kann man prinzipiell sicher verwenden, wenn auch vielleicht nicht im Beispielsatz.

> Mein Sofa hat eine Rundecke.

Comment: Eine Rundecke scheint aber eher ein Sofatyp zu sein.

Answer (score 3):

Noch eine Möglichkeit, allerdings wieder nicht passend für den Beispielsatz: Fase

Es handelt sich um „gebrochene“ Kanten, d. h., die Kante wird im Winkel von 45° abgeschliffen.

> Mir gefällt die Tischplatte mit Fasen besser.

auch als Verb:

> Die Tischplatte hat gefaste Kanten.
>
> Ich habe mir die Kanten vom Schreiner abfasen lassen.

Comment: Passend zum Beispiel würden Maschinenbauer (ich bin keiner, aber rede ab und zu mit welchen) von einer Kante mit Radius sprechen.

Answer (score 3):

Ich kenne noch **runde Ecken** - klingt nach Kontradiktion, wird aber benutzt und verstanden.